# Test with yq if the value is a map or a string

Tags: select, filter, yaml, yq

I have YAML that contains the `image` key with both forms:

```
image: my/dockerimage:1.2.3
```

and

```
image:
  description: this i a string
  type: another string
```

I need to process this YAML and filter only the keys where `image` is a string (not a map).

How can I do this with `yq`?

Comment: Can you define `map`?   Is this the same as `folder`?  What is the difference (when a map is a folder) between the string "temp" and the map "temp" ?

Comment: `map`, as in `dictionary`, `hash`. The way `yq` documentation uses it: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/keys#map-keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) has been used here (with the `eval` syntax), you can solve the problem by explicitly matching the `.image` to be of string type, which is represented as `!!str` in yq. So you need below to get the value of `.image`

```
yq 'select(.image|type == "!!str").image'
```

Note that, if you are using `yq` version [above 4.18.1](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1), the eval action `e` is the default one and can be skipped altogether.